# How to press on first button, release on second button and get touch events of second button?

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

I have 2 buttons. This is what I am doing:

1. I press button 1
2. Then I move my finger to button 2
3. I release on button 2

[image]

I set touch listeners for 2 buttons. It is logging touch events for both buttons:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 1: DOWN");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 1: MOVE");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 1: UP");
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: DOWN");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: MOVE");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: UP");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This code logs following information:

- Button 1: DOWN
- Button 1: MOVE
- Button 1: MOVE
- ...
- Button 1: MOVE
- Button 1: MOVE
- Button 1: UP

As you can see, button 2 is not getting touch event.

Question: how to press on first button, release on second button and get touch events on second button?

Answer (score 0):

```
 button2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: DOWN");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: MOVE");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d("ButtonTouchTag", "Button 2: UP");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

it should return true.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not help. I think that that boolean value identifies should onClick method should be called or not.

Comment: did u check ur code? u are returning false instead of true.

Comment: yes checked my code, checked your code. there is no difference. I think problem should be on another

Comment: `button2.setOnTouchListener` it should return true and u wrote `return false;`